# How can i open external links with fancybox

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox, lightbox

I was looking for some help with an issue im having. I have a WordPress site and my theme already has fancybox integrated. I would like for external links on my site to open in fancybox also instead of just pictures which is the default now. Below is where fancybox is called in my scripts.js

```
    // Lightbox Init
var fancyboxArgs = {
    padding: 0,
    overlayColor: "#000",
    overlayOpacity: 0.85,
    titleShow: false
};
$('.gallery-icon a').attr('rel', 'post-gallery');
$("a[rel='gallery'], a[rel='lightbox'], .gallery-icon a, .colorbox").fancybox( fancyboxArgs );`
```

How will the code look like to initate fancybox on external links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, Fancybox is initialised on DOM elements that matches this selector

```
$("a[rel='gallery'], a[rel='lightbox'], .gallery-icon a, .colorbox")
```

If you want to add external links to that selector you can try to add `a[target='_blank']` to the selector like so:

```
$("a[target='_blank'], a[rel='gallery'], a[rel='lightbox'], .gallery-icon a, .colorbox")
```

However, this only works if the external links are currently opening in a tab. If that's not the case, you'd need to add something to your external links that would differentiate them from internal ones such as a CSS class or a data attribute and add that to the selector.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is set up another function to search for a class of "external", then have fancybox open that in an iframe. You can easily adjust [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/open-external-links-in-new-window/) to attach a class to external links.